# Read the Health/Status of USB Modem - Linux

Tags: linux, networking, usb, modem

I am using E8231 Huawei Modem.

I a currently debugging a network connectivity issue and a way to see the health of the USB Modem would be great.

The USB Modem has LED indicators on them which tell the status of the connection(Connecting/connected to 3g/3g+/offline).

I would like to know the same programmatically or from linux shell, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `echo`, `putty`, `socat`,... to send AT commands to the modem, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97242/how-to-send-at-commands-to-a-modem-in-linux , https://brunomgalmeida.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/send-at-commands-to-usb-modem , https://content.konekt.io/blog/using-at-commands-with-the-huawei-e303/

in http://www.zeeman.de/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/ubinetics-at-command-set.pdf is an AT command set for UbiNetics modem

in http://www.3g-modem-wiki.com/page/HUAWEI+AT-commands is a set of HUAWEI AT commands

USB modems are on `/dev/ttyACMx` or `/dev/ttyUSBx` (CDC device class, usually ACM sub-class, kernel module `cdc_acm`)